# MS Dynamics 365 CRM online - dump entity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I'm a newbie in Dynamics 365. We are using Dynamics 365 CRM online version.
I need to dump a couple of entities to our local SQL server.

I've found many examples, but not with the entire entity (including lookup columns).

What is not working for me in this (most relevant) sample:

1. I need a list of all columns (Do I really need to specify the complete column list in new Contact{}?)
2. Get lookup values in result instead of IDs (guids)

   ```
                `var orgContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);
                // Retrieve the Contact records that we created previously.
                List<Contact> contacts = (from c in orgContext.CreateQuery<Contact>()
                                          where c.Address1_City == "New York"
                                          select new Contact
                                          {
                                              ContactId = c.ContactId,
                                              FirstName = c.FirstName,
                                              LastName = c.LastName
                                          }).ToList<Contact>();
                Console.Write("Contacts retrieved, ");'
   ```

Comment: Microsoft Dynamics 365 includes a [whole line of ERP and CRM products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_365), please be specific in indicating the one you are using. Many, if not all, have an online component/platform. Some products like Dynamics 365 Finance have [built in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/analytics/export-entities-to-your-own-database) support to export data entities to an external database (no custom code required).

Comment: The underlying Microsoft Dataverse (used to be named "Common Data Service" or "CDS") can also be leveraged to export data entities ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/why-cds-import-export)). [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/data-export-service#programming-for-the-data-export-service) lists an API that can be used if you want to code something yourself.

Comment: Our company uses a global on-line solution, with no chance to the admin part of Dynamics365. but we are allowed to code custom export code.. Sounds silly, but that the main set-up. I d love write service which uses CDS to dump (sync and delta sync) some Dynamincs Entities to local SQL server. What i really id love to find is a sample of  entity (ideally Actitivity pointer) dump in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though what you’re doing is good practice, which is having defined list of attributes being mentioned in `select` list, you can select all the attributes by using below syntax. It’s worth to mention that this will have huge performance impact.

```
List<Contact> contacts = (from c in orgContext.CreateQuery<Contact>()
                                   where c.Address1_City == "New York"
                                   select c).ToList<Contact>();
```

Coming to your next question - getting lookup field, for that you can use `join`. For ex. Getting primary contact lookup from account using below syntax. This uses primary key and foreign key between entities to join.

```
var accountQuery = from account in context.CreateQuery("account")
                   join contact in context.CreateQuery("contact")
                   on account["primarycontactid"] equals contact["contactid"]
                   where account["name"] ==   "Some Company Name"
                    select new {
                           Name = account["name"],
                           Email = account["emailaddress1"],
                           Manager = contact
                      };

foreach (var account in accountQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(account.Name + " is run by: " + account.Manager["fullname"]);
}
```

[Read more](http://www.powerxrm.com/querying-crm-data-with-linq/)

Querying using LINQ is one way, there are other ways like web api, fetchxml and query expression to do the same job. You have to still do capture the last run time of your dumping job and filtering delta data using createdon and modifiedon time stamp greater than last run time stamp.

Needless to say, Activity is the most cumbersome entity involving multiple tables as Activity pointer, Activity party, etc.

Comment: Hi Arun. Thank you very much for your reply. 

When I need to ADD in regular entity all lookups so do I need to finish that job manually? (eg. for the original column in Account entity "created by"  I see, I can join lookup table value... BUT  My goal is to make data pump from on-line CRM To local. And I'm trying to avoid a lot of work joining all the lookups... (there are SO many tables with INSANE number of lookups..  
 I found ODBC driver from C-DATA company.... but i dont want to be DEPENDEnt on 3dr party SW...

Comment: @PavelKohout of course you have to store all the reference tables, related tables data and then main transactional data to avoid link breakage. This is exactly what Data export service or that CDATA ODBC driver does.

Comment: Some open-source solution that maps all entities with included lookups that would be the GREAT solution for me...

Comment: @PavelKohout if you just need lookup name, you will get in the same parent query like my answer. If you need everything related to systemuser, account, contact, etc then you have to dump them first. I afraid this is yet not available today what you’re asking for free :)

Comment: @arnun I see, that good thing takes $$, but which one. If we skip the budget part of the problem, there is a security reason. There are couple of suppliers of "ODBC, ADO, ... " drivers for DX 365, but... the company data are flows thru it... Which company is ok? which not? I didnt find any "Microsoft recommended" partner... Thats why I start the pain full yourney to make own dat pump :)

Comment: @PavelKohout there is always some trade off wrt Buy vs build strategy. You can build denormalized one big table dump incase you dont want normalized multiple table dumps. Upto you. Pls upvote/accept if my answer was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

you can very easily do so with Excel Export feature from Dynamics 365 (CRM)

Simply add all Columns to an advanced find view.

1. Advanced Find Button
2. Entity selector (look for)
3. Edit Columns
4. Add all Columns to View (see separate picture below for more instructions).
5. View Results

[image]

[image]

If you have more than 100000 records you might hit the limit.

"We're about to generate your Dynamics 365 data in an Excel file (more than 5000 records). If there are more than 100000 records, only the first 100000 will be exported."

In addition to buypass the 100000 limit you can use [Export to Excel Tool from XRM Toolbox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/Ryr.XrmToolBox.ExportToExcel/) which can help you get all the records without any coding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the has to be done using c#  .net library. Not as manual job... Do you have example of export of entity as c# code (eg. activity pointer entity with all lookup columns included)

Comment: If you use Export to Excel from XRM Toolbox, this in turn uses c# code. Will it not solve your purpose?